# Fetching user information on Messaging Extension (Microsoft Teams)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-teams

I have a messaging extension that will be used with our VoIP system.

Let's say I have a 1:1 conversation with another user. I want my messaging extension to be able to fetch the other user's information (Name, email, AadObjectId, etc). The closest information I get is the Conversation ID of the 1:1 chat with that user. I then tried both the following:

SDK:

```
List<ChannelAccount> teamMembers = (await turnContext.TurnState.Get<IConnectorClient>().Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id).ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList();
```

As well as the direct endpoint with the conversation id:

```
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/{REDACTEDCONVERSATIONID}/members
```

Both gave me error 403 (Forbidden) with the message:

```
    "error": {
    "code": "BotNotInConversationRoster",
    "message": "The bot is not part of the conversation roster."
}
```

We really need the messaging extension to be able to pull that information out, is there any way we can do so?

I am using the BotFramework SDK, latest version

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about the recipient of the action? Do you mean the person who posted that original question? Is this a "message" message extension (as opposed to Compose Box or Command Bar message extension)?

Comment: This is a compose box/command bar message extension and I want to retrieve the information from the user in the group where I execute the action

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I updated the question

Comment: ahhh ok, got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you've discovered, you can't do this the way you're trying to, via the bot directly (i.e. via the 'conversations' endpoints) if the bot is not actually installed into that particular location (1-1 chat, channel, etc.). However, this definitely -is- possible, just via another route. What you need to do is to use Microsoft Graph, in particular the operations to get [conversation members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). However, in order to do this, you'll need to implement sign in in your Message Extension. Fortunately, there was a discussion on this *exact* topic in the latest [Teams community call](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwvHpKUM9Cg) from this month. The sample is in node, but the same applies to C# (what I see you're using).

Comment: The conversation members endpoint keeps giving me a badrequest

Comment: Ask it rather as a separate question, so that others will see it better and can help